# Are there any other gamepads compatible with xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

Since Xbox 360 joysticks are more expensive than other ones, are there any other compatible joysticks for use with the Xbox 360?

Can the PS2, PS3 or PC joysticks work with the Xbox 360?

Comment: PS2 and PS3 gamepads don't work on Xbox 360. There are adapters that can make them work, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy other third party controllers. As for PlayStation controllers, they require a special adapter to them.